# Delete ClearCase development stream

Tags: clearcase

In ClearCase, I created my own development stream by going to 'Join Project' and selecting my ClearCase project. Now, when I right click on my development stream, I was expecting to see an option for 'Delete Stream' but I cannot see it.

Is there a way I can delete it, or can it only be done by a ClearCase administrator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to delete your Stream, provided:

- it is your Stream (you created it when joining the project)
- it is empty (no attached view, no activity)

Make sure, however, to right click on it on the *right* side of the project explorer (not on the *left* side).
See "[Using mainline projects and composite baselines to manage large-scale J2EE development with IBM Rational ClearCase](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0124_hu/)" for more on the ClearCase ProjectExplorer in general.

[image: delete on cc project explorer]

Comment: See all the limitations on `cleartool rmstream` at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmstream.htm

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure it is a stream you created yourself (e.g. that you own).
2. If there's an attached view to the stream, the view needs to be deleted first.
3. If the attached view has activities, they need to be deleted first.
4. If the activities have files checked in, they need to be discarded from the activity first.

Once all of this check list is completed, you can delete your empty stream:
While your empty stream is selected, click on "File" on the upper left corner, and select "Delete".

If I remember right, you can probably also use the "Delete" key on your keyboard.

I'm also pretty sure this "Delete" trick also works for empty activities attached to views.

That's it.